# Why cant I install mysqlclient==1.3.10

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm using a new MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

I first installed python3 using Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install python
```

then I cloned my python project repository from github which has a requirements.txt file which has the line:

```
mysqlclient==1.3.10
```

I then created a virtual env and ran pip install:

```
python3 -m venv venv
pip install -r api/requirements.txt
```

and then I get the following error:

```
...
...
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, aniso8601, 
appdirs, jmespath, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, click, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, Flask-Cors, blinker, Flask-Mail, jsonschema, pytz, flask-restplus, Flask-Script, SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session, Mako, python-editor, alembic, Flask-Migrate, PyJWT, Flask-JWT-Simple, idna, pycparser, cffi, asn1crypto, cryptography, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests, nexmo, pyparsing, packaging, Pillow, phonenumbers, numpy, timezonefinder, decorator, ratelim, geocoder, SQLAlchemy-Utils, mysqlclient, pycrypto, simple-crypt, suds-jurko, Salesforce-FuelSDK, schedule, python-utils, progressbar2, timeago
  Running setup.py install for aniso8601 ... done
  Running setup.py install for itsdangerous ... done
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... done
  Running setup.py install for blinker ... done
  Running setup.py install for Flask-Mail ... done
  Running setup.py install for Flask-Script ... done
  Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy ... done
  Running setup.py install for Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session ... done
  Running setup.py install for Mako ... done
  Running setup.py install for python-editor ... done
  Running setup.py install for Flask-JWT-Simple ... done
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Running setup.py install for geocoder ... done
  Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy-Utils ... done
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/mvi/mvi/server/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zh/p8bfpbd166758zz6vj60jd100000gn/T/pip-install-vls9kk27/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/zh/p8bfpbd166758zz6vj60jd100000gn/T/pip-record-6eq5p42p/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mvi/mvi/server/venv/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/mvi/mvi/server/venv/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/mvi/mvi/server/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zh/p8bfpbd166758zz6vj60jd100000gn/T/pip-install-vls9kk27/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/zh/p8bfpbd166758zz6vj60jd100000gn/T/pip-record-6eq5p42p/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mvi/mvi/server/venv/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zh/p8bfpbd166758zz6vj60jd100000gn/T/pip-install-vls9kk27/mysqlclient/
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

On my old mac book pro where I did not have this problem. 
On that macbook I have python 3.6.5 using GCC 4.2.1.
On this new macbook I have python 3.7 using clang 9.1.0
(venv) $ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 15:22:33) 
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin

This article is the only thing I can that seems related but doesnt seem to help much...

https://medium.com/@MrWeeble/homebrew-on-mac-and-pythons-mysqlclient-ea44fa300e70

any ideas for debugging would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need the MySQL client library and its related headers.

These are supplied in e.g. the MariaDB (MySQL fork) package in Brew, so `brew install mariadb` should do the trick.